# Como fijar el numero de decimales de latitud y longitud de lecturas de gps en android studio

Tags: android, gps

Estoy obteniendo lecturas de gps usando estas lineas de codigo:

```
String mLatitud = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
String mLongitud = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
```

El problema esta en que en algunas ocaciones la cantidad de decimales `varia de 6 a 15 decimales`, yo necesitos que `latitud tenga 6 decimales` y `longitud 5 decimales`.

Como puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase `DecimalFormat` para definir la cantidad de decimales:

Defines el formato de esta forma:

```
DecimalFormat precisionLatitude = new DecimalFormat("0.000000"); //6 decimales
DecimalFormat precisionLongitude = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");  //5 decimales
```

Aplicas el formato:

```
String mLatitud = String.valueOf(precisionLatitude.format(location.getLatitude()));
String mLongitud = String.valueOf(precisionLongitude.format(location.getLongitude()));
```